# Node child process.exec error on invoking Git Gui

Tags: node.js, git

I am trying to launch Git GUI using node, the given snippet launches the Git GUI properly but when i try to close the GUI window, it gives an error saying

"Command Failed: Git GUI"

and also gives an error Code : 259

Can anyone help me on this ?

```
var path = require('path')
    , config = require('config')
    , child_process = require('child_process')
    , exec = child_process.exec

var cwd = 'D:\\';

exec('git gui'
        , {
            cwd: cwd
        }, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error !== null) {
                console.error('exec error: ' + error);
            }

            //Execute the callback. 
            console.log("EXIT");
});
```

Comment: Do `stdout` or `stderr` contain any useful information? I love Git GUI, but sometimes I wonder if it was built all that well -- it's possible that error code 259 is just a bad shutdown for some unknown reason (unrelated to your code)

Comment: No there is no information in stdout or stderr